# where is the source code of appcompat-v28?

Tags: android

I create an new android project and want to read the source code of AppCompatActivity.java. but only the class file was found.  the link of Download Sources not work. where is the source code of appcompat-v28?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhM13.png)

[Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nPvL.png)

Comment: [AppCompatActivity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/d25af35/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java)

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0

Comment: is there some way to associate the source code to android studio directly?

Comment: go to sdk manager and download from there

Comment: i already update  the sdk tools. But the problem remains.  i search the sdk folder， only there folders.

Comment: Does anyone actually know why you can't view the full code in Android Studio? And why there's a "Download Sources" button that never works? It's clearly better to view the code from within the IDE rather than a webpage.